# How to filter and delete an item by using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

When I click the delete button on each item, I want to remove the item with a filter. But I don't know how to solve it correctly. I'm a bit confused at this point. hope someone can explain this. Thanks a lot.

**cartSlice.js**

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState:{
      products: [],
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0,
    },
  reducers: {
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
    //filter right here
      state.products = action.payload.idItem;
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
  },
});
```

**Cart.jsx**

```js
const Cart = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.cart.products);

  const handleDeleteItem = (idItem, price, quantity) => {
    const filter = items.filter((item) => item.itemId !== idItem);
    console.log('idItem', idItem);
    console.log('filter', filter);
    dispatch(deleteItem({ idItem, price, quantity }));
  };

  return (
    <>
     {cart.products.map((product) => (
                      <tr className={styles.body} key={product._id}>
                        <td className={styles.column}>
                          <span className={styles.quantity}>{product.quantity}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td className={styles.column}>
                          <span className={styles.total}>${product.price * product.quantity}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td className={styles.column}>
                          <button
                            onClick={() => handleDeleteItem(product.idItem, product.price, product.quantity)}
                            className={styles.deleteItem}
                          >
                            Delete
                          </button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}               
    </>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

[Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXP4.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer you say, the new product is the idItem key :

```
  reducers: {
    deleteItem: (state, action) => {
    //filter right here
      state.products = action.payload.idItem;
      state.quantity -= 1;
      state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
  },
```

But in your cart, you don't pass the filter as parameters :

```
  const handleDeleteItem = (idItem, price, quantity) => {
    const filter = items.filter((item) => item.itemId !== idItem);
    console.log('idItem', idItem);
    console.log('filter', filter);
    dispatch(deleteItem({ idItem, price, quantity }));
  };
```

Shouldn't it be

```
  const handleDeleteItem = (idItem, price, quantity) => {
    const filter = items.filter((item) => item.itemId !== idItem);

    dispatch(deleteItem({ idItem: filter, price, quantity }));
  };
```